# React Apollo SSR getDataFromTree not waiting for query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to set up SSR for my React app, which uses Apollo Client for graphql requests to an API. I've set up the webpack config, and the Express app, correctly, and I can see the components getting loaded. The issue here is that `getDataFromTree` is not waiting for my query at all. It simply returns the component with `loading: true` and then nothing. I set `ssrForceFetchDelay` as well to make the client refetch the queries, but nothing.

I keep getting `window.__APOLLO_STATE__={}`. The components are very basic, making simple queries and displaying the result.

This is my express app:

```
    app.use((req, res) => {
     const client = new ApolloClient({
     ssrMode: true,
     link: new HttpLink({
      uri: 'http://localhost:8000/graphql',
      fetch: fetch
     }),
     cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    });
    const app = (
     <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Router location={req.url} context={{}}>
        <App client={client}/>
      </Router>
     </ApolloProvider>
    );
   const jsx = extractor.collectChunks(app); // Using loadable

   renderToStringWithData(jsx).then((dataResp) => {   
    const content = dataResp;   
    const state = client.extract(); // Always {}
    const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
    const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
      <Html content={content} helmet={helmet} assets={assets} state={state} />,
    );
    res.status(200); res.send(`<!doctype html>${html}`);
    res.end();
    }).catch(err => {
     console.log(`Error thrown`);
    }); 
   });

   app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on ${port} port`);
   });
```

This is my client-side Apollo config:

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache().restore(window.__APOLLO_STATE__);
const client = new ApolloClient({
  ssrForceFetchDelay: 300,
  link: links,
  cache: cache,
  connectToDevTools: true,
});
```

My App :

```
const Wrapped = () => {
    console.log(`Inside Wrapped`);
    return (
    <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}> //The client one
        <Router>
            <App />  /*Only returns 2 basic components */
        </Router>
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  };

  hydrate(<Wrapped />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I can see the components on the page, but no queries have been loaded and APOLLO_STATE is always empty. I've been following the documentation on `react-apollo` to set this up, but I can't understand why this basic set up won't work. Any ideas on what I need to change here? Thanks!

Html component:

```
import React from 'react';

const Html = ({ content, helmet, assets, state }) => {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
        />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        {helmet.meta.toComponent()}
        {helmet.title.toComponent()}
        {assets.css &&
          assets.css.map((c, idx) => (
            <link key={idx} href={c} rel="stylesheet" />
          ))}
      </head>

      <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }} />
        <script
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `window.__APOLLO_STATE__=${JSON.stringify(state).replace(
              /</g,
              '\\u003c',
            )};`,
          }}
        />
        {assets.js &&
          assets.js.map((j, idx) => (
            <script key={idx} src={j} />
          ))}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
};

export default Html;
```

EDIT: Added my HTML component code

Link to repo with basic code that is working correctly. I intend to add Loadable to this to see if that is what is causing the issue.

https://github.com/kvnam/gql-ssr-test

Comment: What's the code for the `Html` component you're using?

Comment: @DanielRearden Added the code for the Html component as well.

Comment: Are you still facing this issue ? I can't find anyway to load the queries on the server... I found people with same issues on the offical repo but nothing so far have worked.

Comment: I upgraded to `apollo-client : 2.6.8` and `react-apollo: 3.1.3` and now I'm using `getDataFromTree` from `'@apollo/react-ssr'` and it's working as expected. ApolloProvider is from `@apollo/react-common`. I also switched to sharing the same Apollo client config on the client and server. I had to also ensure that all these packages are singletons, so if you're using a component library or something, ensure there is only a single version of these being used by everything. Hope something in here helps!